# How to set a text from parsed json variable in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a problem with parsed JSON in Flutter-Dart. Actually, there is no problem, but there is a method which I don't know. I'm getting data from a PHP server and I'm writing to listview from parsed JSON. However, I don't want to write to a listview, I just want to get data from the parsed JSON because I will set an another textview from parsed json data which I get.

This is my code.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get(Uri.parse('https://meshcurrent.online/get_20word.php'));
    
  

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Photo {
  final String questId;
  final String quest;
  final String ans1;
  final String ans2;
  final String ans3;
  final String ans4;
  final String correctAns;
  final String category;

  const Photo({
    required this.questId,
    required this.quest,
    required this.ans1,
    required this.ans2,
    required this.ans3,
    required this.ans4,
    required this.correctAns,
    required this.category,
  });

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Photo(
      questId: json['questId'] as String,
      quest: json['quest'] as String,
      ans1: json['ans1'] as String,
      ans2: json['ans2'] as String,
      ans3: json['ans3'] as String,
      ans4: json['ans4'] as String,
      correctAns: json['correctAns'] as String,
      category: json['category'] as String,
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Text("ronalddo"),
          Text("mecsfsi"),
          FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
            future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data!);
              } else {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ]));
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotosList({Key? key, required this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Photo> photos;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: photos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Text(photos[index].quest),
                Text(photos[index].ans1),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

I want to do get only first column and get only questId from this parsed JSON. And I will set a textview using Getx library. I know set a data with Getx library but I can't do it because I don't know get the data.

Comment: "_I want to do get only first column..._": what do you mean by _column_?

Comment: I mean item of list. First item, second item or etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the first *questId* of the `List`, do

```
photos[0].questId;
```